Nexus hub - why is the sprocket being dragged round by a dust cap?
I've got Nexus 7 hub on my folding bike.  When I push it (which I do quite a bit, through various stations) the pedals rotate, but not forcefully.  At first I thought it was sticky grease in the freewheel mechanism, as the bike had been unused for a few years.  But servicing that didn't fix it.  When I looked more closely I could see that the sprocket is rubbing on a metal ring, part of the dust cap.  Leaving this off stops the rubbing, but it's clearly meant to be there.

I haven't been able to assemble it any differently, and everything has to be pushed together tightly for me to be able to assemble the sprocket and shifter.
So why is it rubbing, or more importantly, what can I do about it.

The way it's supposed to work is the big plastic/rubber dust cap is fixed on the hub shell and the outer metal dust cap rides on the driver under the cog and is held in place along with the cog by the cog snapring. So the metal cap is supposed to be turning against the plastic one. If something disrupts that it will turn the driver as the wheel turns, driving the chain and pedals forward.
This can happen if the plastic cap isn't fully seated on the shell, or if the metal cap is deformed, or if the interface between them is too dirty or potentially too dry (you don't want a lot of lubrication there but 1-2 drops of oil is okay and may fix it) or if the cog is flipped the right direction and compressing the metal cap too much because of it.
I've occasionally seen the metal cap get smooshed for who knows what reason and had to rework them flat again.

Yep - I'd suspect dirt based on the shadows in the photo.   Clean and dry, then perhaps even adding a couple of drops of superglue to the non-moving area to help.

@Criggie there may well be some dirt at the interface Nathan mentioned because I concentrated on cleaning the other side, against the sprocket.  but it's very greasy and wet, so what's visible is just beaded water and excess grease
